# Can I add a folder to the right side of the Start Menu in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I have a backup folder under D:\ and I download and keep everything there. I want to access it quickly like My Documents, so I am asking:

Is it possible to add a folder to Windows 7 start menu below My Computer, My Documents (not the usual place we pin favorite programs.)
Or a better one: is there a way to change the path to one of these special folders without causing complications. Thanks for your support.

Comment: You may want to check [this site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127425(v=vs.85).aspx). It is possible, but need to know some programming. And I am not suggesting to do some windows programming on your own.

Answer (score 5):

This is a rather trivial item, and uses for many types of services.  Pretty easy to accomplish:

- **Right Click** on your start button, and click **Properties**.
- **Click** on **Customize**

[image]

- **Scroll** down to see **Recorded TV**, and set to **Display as Link**

[image]

- **Open Start Menu**
- **Right Click** on **Recorded TV** and click **Properties**
- **Click** the folder in the list at the top, click on **Remove** and click on **OK**

[image]

- **Open Start Menu**
- **Right Click** on **Recorded TV** and click **Rename**
- Give it a name that you want, like **Downloads**, when done, press 'Enter' on keybaord
- **Right Click** on the **Recorded TV [now renamed]**, and click **Properties**

[image]

- Click on **Include a folder**, and then navigate to the folder you want, and click on **Include Folder**:

[image]

- Click **OK**, and now you have a working folder on the right hand side of your start menu.

[image]

Comment: I enjoy this idea, considering hardly anyone I know uses the recorded TV folder.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted. I don't even use My Videos etc. anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Right click "Documents" on the right side of the expanded start menu and hit properties. Then remove the current folders and include the one you want.

This will make the default "documents" link go to the folder you want.

You can also go to the properties of the start menu and customize "documents" to display as a link and add more folders that way

You can do the same thing with "downloads" and just point to your intended target. It depends on which "main folder" header you want to utilize.